# inotify_add_watch fails with errno ESUCCESS

Tags: python, linux, ctypes, inotify, errno

On Linux 2.6.16, [`inotify_add_watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_add_watch) fails and sets errno to `ESUCCESS` (`0`) if the path does not exist. Where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html) wrapper, and `errno` was not being saved. The solution is to pass `use_errno=True` to [`CFUNCTYPE`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CFUNCTYPE).